# MySqlDataReader stops reading after about 4 minutes and returns

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

I have a simple query which returns 25,026 rows:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM People", DB);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

(`ID` is an `int`.)  If I just do this:

```
int i = 0;
while (reader.Read()) i++;
```

`i` will equal 25026.  However, I need to do some processing on each ID in my loop; each iteration ends up taking somewhere in the hundreds of milliseconds.

```
int i = 0;
MySqlCommand updater = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO OtherTable (...)", anotherConnection);
updater.Prepare();
while (reader.Read()) {
     int id = reader.getInt32(0);
     // do stuff, then
     updater.ExecuteNonQuery();
     i++;
}
```

However, after about 4:15 of processing, `reader.Read()` simply returns false.  In most of my test runs, `i` equaled 14896, but it also sometimes stops at 11920.  The `DataReader` quitting after the same number of records is suspicious, and the times it stops after a different number of rows seems even stranger.

Why is `reader.Read()` returning false when there's definitely more rows?  There are no exceptions being thrown – not even first chance exceptions.

---

**Update:** I mentioned in my response to [Shaun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350153/mysqldatareader-stops-reading-after-about-4-minutes-and-returns/3480458#3480458) that I was becoming convinced that `MySqlDataReader.Read()` is swallowing an exception, so I downloaded [Connector/Net's source code](https://code.launchpad.net/~mysql-clr-team/connectornet/6.2) (`bzr branch lp:connectornet/6.2 C:/local/path`) and added the project to my solution.  Sure enough, after 6:15 of processing, **an exception!**

The call to `resultSet.NextRow()` throws a `MySqlException` with a message of "Reading from the stream has failed."  The `InnerException` is a `SocketException`:

```
{ Message: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host",
  ErrorCode: 10054,
  SocketErrorCode: ConnectionReset }
```

10054 means the TCP socket was aborted with a `RST` instead of the normal disconnection handshake (`FIN`, `FIN ACK`, `ACK`), which tells me something screwy is happening to the network connection.

In my.ini, I cranked `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` to 1814400 (seconds) to no avail.

So... why is my connection getting torn down after reading for 6:15 (375 sec)?

(Also, why is this exception getting swallowed when I use the official binary?  It *looks* like it should bubble up to my application code.)

Comment: What does the 14895th insert statement look like?  Also, just an observation, but 4:15 is 255s.  Is there a counter somewhere related to either the reader or the insert experiencing a silent overflow?

Comment: @Tahbaza: The insert is nothing different from the rest.  Anyway, since it's executing on a second `MySqlConnection`, it shouldn't affect the first one that the `DataReader` is on.  As far as the time, it's 4:15 ±15s; I haven't done any precise timing.  I don't have any counters other than `i`, so I don't think it's an overflow.

Comment: Have you checked if it's a script execution timeout?

Comment: @robert: This runs in an exe, so there's no ASP script timeout to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm just reading `int`s, I ultimately just read the entire resultset into a `List<int>`, closed the reader, and then did my processing.  This is fine for `int`s since a even a million take up < 100 MB of RAM, but I'm still disappointed that the root issue isn't resolved – if I were reading more than a single `int` per row, memory would become a very large problem with a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have a corrupted table - this guy's problem sounds very similar to yours: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1507319.aspx?PageIndex=2 - repair the table and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, read on:

My guess is that you are hitting some type of Deadlock, especially considering you are reading and writing. This would explaing why it works with the simple loop, but doesn't work when you do updates. It would also explain why it happens around the same row / time each time.

There was a weird bug in SqlDataReader that squelched exceptions (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316667). There might be something similar in MySqlDatareader - After your final .Read() call, try calling .NextResult(). Even if it's not a deadlock, it might help you diagnose the problem. In these type of situations, you want to lean more towards "trust but verify" - yes, the documentation says that and exception will be thrown on timeone, but sometimes (very rarely) that documentation lies :) This is especially true for 3rd party vendors - e.g. see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53439 - the mysql .net library has had a couple of problems like the one you are having in the past.

Another idea would be to watch what's happening in your database - make sure data is contantly being fetched up till the row that your code exits on.

Failing that, I would just read all the data in, cache it, and then do your modifications. By batching the modifications, the code would be less chatty and execute faster.

Alternatively, reset the reader every 1000 or so rows (and keep track of what row ID you were up to)

Hope something here helps you with your frustration! :)

Comment: The table repair thing was promising, but trying it on my InnoDB table resulted in "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair." So no dice. Since I'm reading from one table (`People`) and writing to another (`Queue`), a deadlock situation seems unlikely. I did try adding a call to both `Read()` and `NextResult()` after my loop; both returned false. (I expect false from `NextResult()` - there's only one query in the command and therefore one resultset.) At this point, I'm pretty convinced that an exception is getting swallowed somewhere in `Read()`.

Comment: it turns out there is an exception getting swallowed.  See the update to my question.

Comment: Cool :) Now you are getting somewhere. Perhaps it's to do with connection pooling - are you closing your connection each time you do an update, or creating new ones each time? Try switching to pooling=false to verify if it's some type of pooling issue. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6634 seems like the appropriate thread. Otherwise, perhaps you have some rows returning a lot of data? are any of the columns binary data?

Is there a firewall between the app/web server and the database server?

Comment: As for the repair - try this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html - make sure to backup first!! :) - namely:

For storage engines such as InnoDB that REPAIR TABLE does not support, use mysqldump to create a dump file and mysql to reload the file, as described earlier.

Comment: Great answer. Can't see why this wasn't accepted by the OP, as it gives lots of advice and includes the workaround that was finally applied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set longer connection timeout.

Comment: I don't think this is a timeout issue -- especially since there's no exceptions being thrown.  My understanding is that `MySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` is the amount of time `MySqlConnection` will wait when *establishing* a connection, not how long it will keep the connection open.  `MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout` is the amount of time a query is allowed to run on the server.  The default is unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues that make things a bit more confusing than it should be:

The first, as has been mentioned in another post, is that older versions of the MySQL .NET connector were swallowing a timeout exception. I was using mysql.data.dll version 6.1.x and after upgrading to 6.3.6 the exception was being properly thrown.

The second is the default MySQL server timeouts, specifically **net_read_timeout** and **net_write_timeout** (which default to 30 and 60 seconds respectively).

With older versions of mysql.data.dll, when you are performing an action with the data in the datareader loop and you exceed the 60 second default timeout it would just sit there and not do anything. With newer versions it properly throws a timeout exception which helps diagnose the problem.

Hope this helps someone as I stumbled upon this but the solution was to use a different approach, not an actual cause/fix.

**TLDR**: The fix is increase **net_read_timeout** and **net_write_timeout** on the mysql server in my.ini although upgrading mysql.data.dll is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is timeout on server-side?

Comment: I'd think that a timeout on the server would raise an exception.  At any rate, I set ridiculously high timeouts in my server's config and didn't see a change.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout on the MySqlCommand and not the MySqlConnection on both "cmd" and "updater".
What happens if you do : `SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM PEOPLE` ?

Comment: So while the [docs claim](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout) that the default command timeout is unlimited, after browsing the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql-clr-team/connectornet/6.2/annotate/head%3A/MySql.Data/Provider/Source/command.cs#L138), it looks like the default is actually 30 seconds. Either way, a timeout doesn't explain why the `MySqlDataReader` is stopping after 4 minutes. Additionally, command timeout affects query *execution*, not data streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1. Add reference System.Transactions;

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
       //Initialize connection
       // execute command
     :
     :
     scope.Complete();
}
```

Write your entire insert/update logic inside Scope's using. This will definetly help you.

Comment: I don't want these inserts to be committed as part of a transaction.  This code is part of a job which inserts work items into a queue for later processing.  That processing can happen immediately and asynchronously, so each row needs to be available for reading as soon as possible.  If all inserts were wrapped in a transaction, none of the queued items would be available until the entire job completes, thus wasting time.  Worse, if I change the `IsolationLevel` to allow dirty reads, a rollback would wreak havoc - queued items which had already been acted upon would disappear!

Comment: Try adding Application.DoEvents(); or Thread.Sleep(100) after i++

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, but I don't think they're relevant.  This code is not part of a Winforms app; `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` doesn't exist in a Windows Service.  Furthermore, I don't see how pumping Windows messages relates to a database connection (this job runs on its own thread anyway).  I also fail to see how `Thread.Sleep()` does anything but slow down my job.  100 ms * 25,000 rows = ~42 **minutes** sleeping -- no good.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after creating your Command.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

This will set the CommandTimeout to indefinitly. The reason your getting a timeout is probably because the connection though executed, is still in the 'command' phase because of the Reader.

Either try setting the CommandTimeout = 0 or reading everything first, then doing subsequent functions on the results. Otherwise the only other issue i could possibley see is that the Sql Server is dropping the result set against the specified process id due to a timeout on the server itself.

Comment: `CommandTimeout` has no impact on data streaming to a `DataReader`.  It really only applies to the amount of time the SQL statement can execute on the server.  Once the statement completes (and `MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` returns), the timeout value becomes irrelevant; you may take as long as you need to iterate through returned rows using `MySqlDataReader.Read()`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484027/ado-net-datareader-timeout-issue/1484138#1484138) for more.  Also, I can know this is **not** a timeout since no exceptions are being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

i've found an article here
http://corengen.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/mysql-connectornet-hangs-on-mysqldatareader-read/

What this guy experienced was something similar: a hang on the Read method at exactly the same moment, during reading of the same record (which is the same thing you experience i guess).
In his case he called another webservice during the Read() loop, and that one timed out causing the Read() to hang without an exception.

Can it be the same at your machine, that an update in the Read() loop times out (i think that update uses the default 30 secs timeout) and causes the same effect?

Maybe a longshot, but reading the two stories the sounded a lot familiair.

Comment: Interesting article.  I don't think I'm experiencing a hang, though.  The loop runs just fine at a constant speed up to the 14896th record and then `Read()` simply returns false -- there is no hang or delay.